# ¿Como Solucionar el error de llamada a AsEnumerable relacionado con FromSqlRaw?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

**Buenas estoy intentando crear un metodo para recibir la respuesta de un procedimiento almacenado pero me encuentro con un error un error de 'AsEnumerable' lo cambie pero no lo
puedo usar con el 'await' lo que me genera una carga de espera muy larga**

```
   [HttpPost("Respuesta")]
   public async Task<ActionResult<CanalDto>> Respuesta(RespuestaDto resPuestaDto)
    {
        Data results = new Data();
        using (DataContext context = new DataContext())
        {
            try
            {
                results = await context.Set<Data>().FromSqlRaw($"EXECUTE usp_Data       
                @Nombre = '{user.Nombre}'").AsEnumerable();
        
            }
            catch (System.Exception )
            {

                throw   ;
            }
        }
        return new CanalDto
        {
            NombreCanal = user.NombreCanal,
            CodigoCanal = user.CodigoCanal,
            NombreData = results.NombreData,
            CodigoData = results.CodigoData
        };
```

**En esta parte del Codigo Cambio el 'AsEnumerable' por 'ToListAsync' para ello convierto mi Data
en List y ahora me genera otro error en NombreData y CodigoData**

```
    [HttpPost("Respuesta")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<CanalDto>> Respuesta(RespuestaDto resPuestaDto)
    {
        List<Data> results = new List<Data>();
        using (DataContext context = new DataContext())
        {
            try
            {
                results = await context.Set<Data>().FromSqlRaw($"EXECUTE usp_Data  
                @Nombre = '{user.Nombre}'").ToListAsync();
        
            }
            catch (System.Exception )
            {

                throw   ;
            }
        }
        return new CanalDto
        {
            NombreCanal = user.NombreCanal,
            CodigoCanal = user.CodigoCanal,
            NombreData = results.NombreData,
            CodigoData = results.CodigoData
        };
```

**Codigo del Error Generado**

```
 Error CS1061 "List<Data>" no contiene una definición para "NombreData" ni un método de 
 extensión accesible "NombreData" que acepte un primer argumento del tipo "List<Data>"
 (¿falta alguna directiva using o una referencia de ensamblado?)
```

**Estos son los Errores que me Genera**

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'FromSqlRaw' or 'FromSqlInterpolated' was called with non- 
composable SQL and with a query composing over it. Consider calling 'AsEnumerable' after the method to perform the composition on the client side.
```

**Aqui me guie de algunas referencias**

https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/3224

Comment: Seria bueno ver la clase Data, revisar que esta retornando el procedure.

Comment: Yo lo he resultó de esta manera pero 
aquí ya no usarías await ` `context.AsEnumerable.Set<Data>().FromSqlRaw($"EXECUTE usp_Data  
                @Nombre = '{user.Nombre}'").ToList();` igual puedes intentar con  `await Task.Run(()=>context...);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por lo que veo tu problema reside en que la variable results es una lista de tipo Data, y las estas utilizando como un objeto, si el procedure solo va retornar una row, te recomiendo que uses el método `FirstOrDefaultAsync()`
Quedaría algo así:

```
        var result = new Data();
        using (DataContext context = new DataContext())
        {
            try
            {
                result = await context.Set<Data>().FromSqlRaw($"EXECUTE usp_Data  
                @Nombre = '{user.Nombre}'").FirstOrDefaultAsync();
        
            }
            catch (System.Exception )
            {

                throw   ;
            }
        }
```

Espero que esto te funcione.

Comment: Muchas Gracias , si me sirvió tu recomendación.